# Why my input values not storing in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to store my input values into an array.

When i click enter i get the input value and push into `vals` array.

Then i console log but **whenever i click enter, it only push last input value.**

Why?

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ke9d8z3a/)**

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var val = e.target.value;
  var vals = [];

  if (e.which == 13) {

    vals.push(val);
    input.value = " ";
    console.log(vals);

  }

}, false);
```

Comment: Because you re-declare `vals` everytime the `keyup` listener is executed. Move it out of that listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why your code is only displaying the last value is because your array is local to the function hence it only exists while that function is in scope. Rather make it global, that way you can push more than one element into the array and later access it.

```
 var vals = [];   //make this global 

 var input = document.getElementById("input");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var val = e.target.value;
  if (e.which == 13) {

    vals.push(val);
    input.value = " ";
    console.log(vals);

  }

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your array only once

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var vals = [];
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var val = e.target.value;


  if (e.which == 13) {

    vals.push(val);
    input.value = " ";
    console.log(vals);

  }

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the vals array outside of the event listener

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var vals = [];

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    var val = e.target.value;

    if (e.which == 13) {

        vals.push(val);
        input.value = " ";
        console.log(vals);

    }

}, false);
```